# Antigen failing to load theme from .zshrc

Tags: shell, zsh, themes, oh-my-zsh

I have a fresh Debin Bullseye installation and I can't get antigen to load a theme if loading it directly in `.zshrc`.

I installed `zsh` and `zsh-antigen` using `apt`.

My minimal `.zshrc`:

```bsh
source /usr/share/zsh-antigen/antigen.zsh

antigen use oh-my-zsh

antigen bundle git
antigen bundle heroku
antigen bundle pip
antigen bundle lein
antigen bundle command-not-found

antigen bundle zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting

# Load the theme.
antigen theme robbyrussell

# Telling Antigen that I'm done.
antigen apply
```

When I start the `zsh`-shell I get the minimal prompt if no theme is loaded:

```
Computer%
```

No error message is printed.

If I enter `antigen theme robbyrussell` again directly at the prompt, the theme is applied:

```
→  ~
```

This is the same for all themes I tried.

How do I have to load the theme in my `.zshrc` to directly have the theme when starting `zsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution: Deleting the `~/.antigen` directory.

During the first start of `zsh` while using antigen something must have went wrong with loading the theme I preferred. This messed up the `~/.antigen` directory and caused antigen to no longer automatically load the theme.

**Warning:** Deleting the `~/.antigen` directory may have side effects. It is probably safer to just rename it into `~/.antigen-broken` or something similar and checking if `zsh` is working properly before deleting the old directory.